# There is an error importing jpg files on godot

Tags: file, import, godot

I use godot for a game project and i need to import jpg files as textures. However some file importing work whereas other don't with the error message :

```
 editor/editor_file_system.cpp:1800 - Error importing 'res://pictures/cards/actions/actions/black/uni_2.jpg'.
 core/io/image_loader.cpp:69 - Error loading image: res://pictures/cards/actions/actions/black/uni_2.jpg
```

can someone help me ? 
I am using windows. I deal with Godot_v3.2.1 with OpenGL 3.0

Thank you !

Comment: Any chance the image is 16 bit? If so, try converting to 8 bit if you can and try again.

Comment: Could you upload the JPEG image somewhere so we can have a look? (Preferably a host that doesn't modify the image when you upload it, so avoid Imgur.)

Comment: What's the image resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only used png images in my godot games, maybe if you use jpg to png converter it will work :D